# Javafx calling a method form another controller gives Null Pointer exception

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

Im trying to invoke a method of a controller form another controller. But It gives me Null Pointer Exception saying that **java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**.

> Here is my first controller with the method:

```
public class FirstController implements Initializable {

   @FXML
   private AnchorPane pane;
   ...
}
```

Here is the method :

```
public void setFadeEffect(Effect effect) {
    pane.setEffect(effect);
}
```

> Here is my second controller:

```
public class SecondController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button myBtn; 
    ...

    @FXML
    private void myAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FirstController ic = new FirstController();
        ic.setFadeEffect(new GaussianBlur(10));  
    }
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to perform this action please..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch between fxml files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25886632/1759128)

Comment: Consider to work with fx:root based controls/ controllers instead.

Comment: [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) for @Puce's suggestion.